# PHPUnit : convertWarningsToExceptions="false" seems to have no effect

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I've just moved from PHPUnit 3.7.28 to 5.1.4 in a Symfony 2.7 project, and I have errors when I launch tests, that I had not before.

Those errors are exceptions raised by phpunit on PHP warnings. I tried to stop them using `convertWarningsToExceptions="false"` in the configuration file phpunit.dist.xml (and also Errors and Notices, but this should not be necessary) :

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="false"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="false"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="false"
>
```

But the errors are still here. Exemple of such an error in the PHPUnit output:

```
1) AppBundle\Tests\Controller\SecurityControllerTest
exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with  message 'Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « NOT »
LINE 4: CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS website;
                     ^' in /.../AppBundle/Tests/Controller/SecurityControllerTest.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'pg_query(): Que...', '/var/DATA/jenki...', 18, Array)
```

I found a workaround by making silent with @ the function calls throwing the warnings (here pg_query), but I am not satisfied with that solution.

Why is phpunit still converting warnings to exceptions with my config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convertWarningsToExceptions="true"` converts php warnings to PHPUnit exceptions. `convertWarningsToExceptions="false"` disables this functionality. That's all.

You have a `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException` explicitly thrown by some component of your system. It is not a php warning.

Comment: So what is it ? The responsible line for this error is something like `pg_query($connexion, 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS website;');`.  pg_query throws a warning because the schema does exists. If I silent it : `@pg_query($connexion, 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS website;');`, the PHPUnit error disappears.

Comment: First, it is not a PHPUnit error. Second, the `pg_query` error  is caught by one of your components which converts it to `ContextErrorException`. Suppressing the error you make the exception disappear.

Comment: Ok, thank you, this time I got it. So I just have to silent the errors (when I can't suppress them) if I know they're harmless.

Comment: If I get it right, it complines about SQL syntax,  which doesn't seem harmless to me, but it is another problem, not related to PHPUnit.

Comment: In this case it is harmless : it is not a syntax problem ;  pg_query throws a warning on `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS website` because the schema does exists, but the query does what it is supposed to (nothing in this case). So here, there is no real problem. But I have other ones I need to examine closely...